# OpenGL: using FTGL and textures

Tags: opengl, ftgl

When using FTGL texture fonts, everything works perfectly until I use another texture somewhere else in my program. Then the original texture of the font seems to be lost, and as a consequence, the characters are drawn as black dots. After playing with the various parameters of glTexEnvf, I think the problem is simply that the font doesn't load its default texture back when writing.

Is there a way to access this default texture and bind it before writing?

Comment: hm, I've been using FTGL without noticing this problem. From memory, FTGL does not change glActiveTexture, do you change its value from GL_TEXTURE0 ? Did you try to use Push/PopAttrib to try to isolate GL state for FTGL and your app's state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding your calls to rendering the font with

```
  glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
```

and

```
  glPopAttrib();
```

(as rotoglup suggests.)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used FTGL but you could simply be having problems with the active texture unit.

Did you try using a texture unit other than 0 for your own textures and leaving GL_TEXTURE0 to FTGL ?

The relevant documentation is [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) if you need it.